# Number of rows affected should display in log of AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am creating log file using parameter group of AWS RDS. I am getting all query executed on RDS but I want to show "how many and which row affected by this query".

Is it possible? If yes, How?

I am describing more here:

> 2016-10-20 15:30:05 QUERY  : Void query (database-name): UPDATE public."User" SET "Name"='Pooja'::character varying(25) WHERE "UserID" = '10001'::integer

This is correct.

But I want information like

> No Result

OR

> 1 row affected [where UserID = 10001 or OID = 'dsj422']

Comment: Can you define when a row is affected by a query?

Comment: No, Is only shows when query start execution and how much time it take to execute.

Comment: Well, if you cannot tell what you mean by that, how is one supposed to answer the question?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I update question what I expect. Please review and suggest changes

Comment: What programming language and database driver are you using? The answer would depend on these.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Laurentz Albe, the poster is asking about the standard postgresql log, no programming language or driver involved. In AWS (Amazon Web Services) you can configure postgresql using a "parameter group" which contains the same settings as postgresql.conf.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get this information in the PostgreSQL log.